# How to read contents of zip file in another zip file without extraction

Tags: ruby

I have a zip file that contains many zip files. I want to check the contents of an inner zip *without* extracting it to the filesystem.

If I iterate over the the contents of the outer zip file with `Zip::File.foreach` I get a `Zip::Entry` that represents the zip file i want to inspect the contents of. I can't figure out how without to do that without extracting the sub-zip to the filesystem.

I CAN call `.extract("some_destination.zip")` on the su-bzip and then treat it like a normal top level zip). That works, but I'm just trying to verify contents in a unit test and don't want to unnecessarily write things to the file system.

---

Side note: before anyone asks "why" I have sub-zips, or points out the lack of compression value to doing this... It's because Apple wants you to create a zip of zips in order to add multiple tickets to an apple wallet at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to is to read in memory the content of the outer zip entry, then instantiate a new `Zip` instance, by using the `Zip::File.open_buffer` API.

In the following example, we assume, for simplicity, an outer zip file, which includes an inner zip file, which includes a plaintext file:

```rb
require 'zip'
require 'stringio'

outer_zip_file = Zip::File.open('outer.zip')

outer_entry = outer_zip_file.entries.first
outer_entry_data = outer_entry.get_input_stream.read

inner_zip = Zip::File.open_buffer(outer_entry_data)

inner_entry = inner_zip.entries.first
puts inner_entry.get_input_stream.read
```

it's probably possible to use streams to accomplish the same tasks, but it's easier to do mistakes (that is, accidentally reading multiple times while debugging), and if the file is small enough (and of course, there's no risk of attack), reading in memory is acceptable.

Comment: [here's a recursive example](https://gist.github.com/masukomi/9c820dccbb6d9535536ab9945153b48c) implementing this idea to extract the names of all the files